# Alternate asymptotics for the Harmonic Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, harmonic-numbers

It is well known that

$$\displaystyle \mathcal{H}_n \sim \log{n} + \gamma - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{k}}{k \, n^{k}},$$

where $\displaystyle B_k$ are the Bernoulli numbers.

A similar asymptotic expansion for the Harmonic numbers begins with the logarithm shifted slightly:

$$\displaystyle \mathcal{H}_n = \log{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)} + \gamma + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{A_k}{n^k}$$

Is there a closed form for $\displaystyle A_k$ in terms of known number sequences?

The first few terms of $\displaystyle A_k$ are:

$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{24}, -\frac{1}{24}, \frac{23}{960}, -\frac{1}{160}, -\frac{11}{8064}, -\frac{1}{896}, \frac{143}{30720}, -\frac{1}{4608}$$

for $\displaystyle k \in \left[2,\ldots,9 \right]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply write

$$\begin{align}
\log\left(n+\frac12\right)&=\log(n)+\log\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)\\\\
&=\log(n)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2^kk\,n^k}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Your answer is fine :)